# custom http referer with php

Tags: php, http-headers, http-referer, referer

i would like to use `HTTP_REFERER` to send my own referer.

Like this **http://mywebsite.com/spoof.php?newurl=anotherwebsite.com**
this is what i have but doesn't work

spoof.php

```
<?php
  $referer = (www.website.com, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to send people to another url with a spoofed referer? 
thats not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The referrer is controlled by the client (ie. their browser).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer

They send it to the new URL when you redirect them.

Comment: whats the difference between my script and say this -> http://anonym.to/?http://google.com which hides the referer?

Comment: That page uses a meta redirect: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=http://google.com"> Your code just wouldn't run. Parse error.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a request with that PHP file using the spoofed header with cURL, but you can not send the client there.

Best you can do is echo a link with `rel="noreferrer"` and hope the user's browser supports it (and this only nulls the referrer, it doesn't change it). Or alternatively send the `Location` header which will turn the referrer to *your* site.

Comment: whats the difference between my script and say this -> http://anonym.to/?http://google.com which hides the referer?

Comment: @jack That would be having no referrer, not spoofing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override the referrer header that the user's browser sends.  If you want to control the referrer header like that, then your only option is to send the request yourself, by doing either:

1. Have your server act as a proxy for the request.  Construct a new HTTP request server-side, set the referrer header to whatever you want, and return the result to the client.  Note that you will have to rewrite any relative URL's in the target site's markup if you want the page to display and function correctly for the user.
2. Create your own browser (or perhaps browser-plugin) and get people to use that.  Then you can set headers however you want.